# How to hash SHA256 byte 00 with Python?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, python-cryptography

I'm trying to SHA256 a byte b"00" with python but don't understand what I have to encode.

```
import binascii
import hashlib

byte_ = binascii.unhexlify(b"00")
byte_ = b"00".decode("ascii")

hashed_byte = hashlib.sha256(byte_)
print((hashed_byte.hexdigest()))
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does this work with a string and not a byte?

Comment: `b"00"` represents two bytes. Do you mean `b"\x00"`?

Comment: In theory it should be the null byte in python.

Comment: are you asking null message or message that has one byte with value 0?

Comment: "Why does this work with a string and not a byte?" I'm not sure what you mean -- I think you switched "string" and "byte" in this sentence, and I'm not sure what answer you're looking for that's more specific than "because the developers implemented it that way".

Comment: If you run the code, you'll see that altough it's fine it doesn't run.
If I change the b"00" for something else like a string "dog", then it allows me to 256hash.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. "What am I doing wrong? Why does this work with a string and not a byte?" What is "this"? What do you mean by "work"? **What should happen** when you run the code? What happens instead, and how is that different?

Comment: "f I change the b"00" for something else like a string "dog", then it allows me to 256hash." This is not the case. It is the other way around. It will not allow you to hash the string `"dog"`. Just as it will not allow you to hash `b"00".decode("ascii")` **because that is a string, not a `bytes` object**. It does allow you to hash `binascii.unhexlify(b"00")`, because that produces a `bytes` object. (It would also produce a `bytes` object if you gave it a string, like `binascii.unhexlify("00")`.)

Comment: Thanks karl.

The direct question would be, how do I sha256 hash b"00"?
The correct output should be: 6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d

Comment: Then you should hash `b'\x00'`, which represents the value you actually want to hash. `b'00'` means **two** bytes, both of which correspond to the ASCII for the `0` symbol. This is not a question about hashing at all, but a question about how the Python `bytes` type works - and one that is best addressed by following a tutorial or reading the documentation. [For example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) already accepts binary strings.

```py
import hashlib

m = hashlib.sha256()

m.update(b"\x00")  #or use m.update(bytes.fromhex('00'))
hashed = m.hexdigest()

print(hashed)
```

outputs

`6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d`

There are [NIST SHA-256 byte-oriented test vectors](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Secure-Hashing#shavs), however, there is no test vector for `b"\x00"`. I've tested for other byte values like `0xd3` outputs

`28969cdfa74a12c82f3bad960b0b000aca2ac329deea5c2328ebc6f2ba9802c1` correctly.

---

If you want to see the internals see https://sha256algorithm.com/

Comment: The output for the256sha  hashed b"00" should be:

6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d

Comment: Yes, my typo. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `b'\x00'` then you are defining a binary string as indicated [in the comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411280/how-to-hash-sha256-byte-00-with-python#comment127919963_72411280). As you have directly encoded a byte, the compiler or interpreter already performs the conversion. So **you** don't have to perform any conversion afterwards.

Note that for Python 3, you could also use `bytes(1)` which specifies a zero filled byte array of size 1. If you think that is not as readable, you could use `bytes.fromhex('00')`. In both cases the conversion **would** be performed at runtime though, so it has an ever so tiny overhead.

Answer (score -2):

[image: binary value to hexidecimal value]

*The hexadecimal value **00** does not exist in notation.*

All though the value **00** can be represented in both notations, the hexvalue **00** is the same as binary value **0, 00, 000, 0000, 00000000000** *et infinitum*...

This leads to the computational conclusion that *a hexadecimal value **00** could represent an infinite amount of logical gates*.  logical outcomes between hexadecimal **0** and hexadecimal **00** is either one outcome, ***or all outcomes that or not false that proceed....*** This causes... problems... and is not a logical computation that is quantifiable.

> This was the premise for Y2K and the end of the world

**binary 00 -->"true" then "true" value is logically different from binary 0--> "true".**

*Convert them to hexadecimal...*

... you get just hexadecimal 0, which represents binary "true", not binary "true" then 'true".

**its like seeing two true false questions on an exam that is true, and only answer the one to represent both.**

[image: binary 00 to hexidecimal]

**i believe \x00 works for finding 00**